# Autofill Run-time error 1004 Method 'Run' of object ' _Application' Failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched for questions relating autofill method and method 'run' but I still cannot seem to figure out why my code thinks I am using a run method when I am not.

> Run-time error 1004 Method 'Run' of object ' _Application' Failed

I am trying to do an autofill with an array formula. The code works correctly until the line that tries to do the autofill itself. I thought it was a problem with the way I set my ranges but now since the error says "Method Run" I guess that's not it. Can't figure out where I am using run method... [image]

```
rngLastHeader.Offset(1, x).Select
Selection.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(P:P,MATCH(" & """" & city & """&""" & "Cars" & """" & ",I:I&R:R,0))," & """""" & ")"
Set rngDest = Range(rngLastHeader.Offset(1, x).Address, rngLastHeader.Offset(intLastRow - 1, x).Address)
Set rngStart = rngLastHeader.Offset(1, x)
rngStart.AutoFill Destination:=rngDest, Type:=xlFillValues
```

Comment: When creating array formulas in excel you cannot paste the array formula over itself. You have to copy the cell and paste to *different* cells. This makes the `AutoFill` method fail because that method requires the original range to be inside the first argument. I suggest using `.FormulaR1C1` to fill the entire range.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Ohhhhhhhhhh, I see. I did not know that. I will re work to paste formulas. Thank you!!